# How to use setprecision in C++

Tags: c++

I am new in `C++` , i just want to output my point number up to 2 digits.
just like if number is `3.444`, then the output should be `3.44` or if number is `99999.4234` then output should be `99999.42`, How can i do that. the value is dynamic. Here is my code.

```
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << num1 << endl;
}
```

but its giving me an error, undefined fixed symbol.

Comment: Space with the second line at the start, remove that.

Comment: if you're using the standard namespace, you'll need to include `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 48):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << num1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: class name in function main()
Error NONAME00.CPP 7: Statement missing ; in function main()
Error NONAME00.CPP 8: Type qualifier 'std' must be a struct or class name in function main()
Error NONAME00.CPP 8: Statement missing ; in function main()
Error NONAME00.CPP 9: Type qualifier 'std' must be a struct or class name in function main()
Error NONAME00.CPP 9: Statement missing ; in function main()
Warning NONAME00.CPP 10: Function should return a value in function main()
Warning NONAME00.CPP 10: 'num1' is assigned a value that is never used in function main()....
I am facing this error

Comment: Are you sure you copied the include statements from the answer verbatim?

Comment: I think the complaint being referred to is the lack of a return on main.

Comment: @Pradyot FYI, `int main()` can be left without a return value at which point it defaults to returning 0.

Comment: If i dont want to do a cout. just want to set the precision of `num1` to 3 decimal places . How do I do that ?

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads You can't. There is no such thing. The precision of a `double` is fixed; it is an inherent part of the datatype. What we're doing here is altering the _apparent_ precision when we print the number for human consumption.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
```

You can enter the line `using namespace std;` for your convenience. Otherwise, you'll have to explicitly add `std::` every time you wish to use `cout`, `fixed`,  `showpoint`, `setprecision(2)` and `endl`

```
int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << num1 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you added meaning of `showpoint` and `fixed`

Answer (score 4):

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout<<std::fixed;
```

when you are using operator overloading try this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is absolutely correct. Here is a Turbo C++ version of it.

```
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    cout << setiosflags(fixed) << setiosflags(showpoint);
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << num1 << endl;
}
```

For `fixed` and `showpoint`, I think the `setiosflags` function should be used.

Comment: You can use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::showpoint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint) instead, just like the other answers show.  But, if you are going to use `std::setioflags()`, at least combine the flags together, eg: `cout << setiosflags(fixed | showpoint) << ...`

Answer (score 2):

> Replace These Headers

```
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <iomanip>
```

> With These.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
```

Thats it...!!!

Answer (score 1):

Below code runs correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << num1 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>                        // to include all libraries 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
double a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
double x=a/b;                                 //say we want to divide a/b                                 
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(10)<<x;             //for precision upto 10 digit 
return 0; 
}
```

input: 1987 31

output: 662.3333333333                           10 digits after decimal point

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me, I found this in the CPP book by Anthony.

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);
```

- First set the flags to fixed.
- Then set to show decimal points.
- Lastly set the number of decimal places you want after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 
int main(void) 
{
    float value;
    cin >> value;
    cout << setprecision(4) << value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the use of the namespace `std`. If possible, please describe your answer, posting only code is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to print the value of float/double but store it in a string and then print then you can use this. Useful when you want to use set precision without using cout in c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float z = 9.9999;
    string s = "";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << fixed << setprecision(2) << z;
    s += ss.str();
    cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 10.00

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works with any precision setting.
To get precision to 2 decimal places in sstream here is my code snippet.
Examples
3.444 will be 3.44,
1.10 will be 1.10,
and 1.3245 will be 1.32

```
#include<sstream>

std::wostringtream stream;
float value = 3.14159;
// To get the output to 2 decimal places
stream.precision(2);
stream << std::fixed << value;
std::wcout<<stream.str()<<L"\n";

// The output will be 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for setting the fixed and precision is the following (using dot notation with cout rather than <<):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(2);
    // 3.12
    cout << num1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer might provide a correct solution, but it would be helpful to add some textual information on the usage of the code using [edit].