# How to set the output precision to 2 decimal places in C++?

Tags: c++, decimal, precision

I want to globally set the ouptut precision to 2 decimal places.

I already tried to use `iomanip` and `setprecision`, however I keep getting output with 'e' in it.

This is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double pay=16.78;
    double hours;
    double total;

    cout.precision(2); 

    cout << "Please enter how many hours you worked : " << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    total=hours*pay;

    cout << "You earned: " << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You might get better answers faster if you post a minimal example that exhibits the behaviour you wish to demonstrate, not your whole code.

Comment: How to write a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use setprecision in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515592/how-to-use-setprecision-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
double pay = 393.2993;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << pay;
```

You will need to include iomanip for this to work.

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your e is a positive value, you cannot ride of them because your value is too large. This code

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << 3e45;

//output
3e+45
```

If it's a negative number, your precision is not enough. Like the following code

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << 3e-45; //

//output
3e-45
```

A simple way will be to use std::fixed

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << 3.63e-2;

//output
0.036
```

But the disavantage you have with the std::fixed is it shows the zero after the last none-zero number until it reach the setprecision qunatity you set previously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "cout.precision(2)".  I would use std::setprecision(4) if I wanted my output to have 4 significant figures.