# Rounding number to next .05 or whole digits in c++

Tags: math, rounding, digits, price

Sorry if my title was vague, im learning c++ and we're making a checkout/inventory system which calculates currency, if there is any change such as 1.69, it should automatically round up to 1.70 or if it was 1.63 it would round up to 1.65, avoiding giving change in cents.

Heres my relevant code that im attempting to adapt to return the correct rounding:

```
if (!taxed()) {
                    cout << price() * quantity();

                }
                else {
                    cout <<  (price() * quantity()) * 1.13;
                }
```

Please note that i attempted cout precision with no success.

I managed to output to 1.7, but how do you change it to 1.70?

Tried changing the precision but that changed my answer, also setting it to double etc didnt help.

Comment: Add 0.05 to your amount, then do the math.

Comment: @tonypdmtr, to my total amount or price first before adding quantity and the tax?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way:

1. Multiply by 100 (to get wanted value without decimals),
2. Divide by 5 (because that's the precision you want),
3. Round this number. Now reverse the procedure with rounded number:
4. Multiply by 5 and
5. Divide by 100 (to get value with two decimal places).

Note that you can shorten the procedure:

1. Multiply by 20 (previous steps 1 and 2 combined),
2. Round the number,
3. Multiply by 0.05.

The main thing is dividing by wanted precision (5) and rounding it then.

Comment: How do you "round the number"

Comment: Also, multiplying 1.69 by 100 gives me 169, dividing it by 5 gives me 33.8... Multiplying by 5 then dividing by 100 gives me 1.69 again.

Comment: Depending on the version you use, you might not have round() function available. How to do it in that case, you can find some examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c

Comment: About your second comment - that's why you have to round the number. So when you get 33.8, it will be rounded to 34. After multiplying it by 5 (and dividing by 100 then) you get 1.70.

Comment: Not sure how to implement that link into my code. im using g++ compiler so its nifty.

Comment: I managed to output to 1.7 but thats by setting the precision to 1. How can i change it to 1.70?

Comment: Use fixed precision and 2 decimal places: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515592/how-to-use-setprecision-in-c

Comment: without adding 0.05 at the start?

Comment: Yes, without adding. Use this adding only for rounding, if the round() function is not available to you. So if you call your determined price (with quantity and tax) qtPrice, solution would either look like round(qtPrice*20)*0.05 or e.g. floor(qtPrice*20 + 0.05)*0.05

Comment: No way to avoid using round? i dont think it will work with my version.

Comment: Setting my precision to 1 lets it be 1.7, setting it to 2 puts it back at 1.69. I want 1.70

Comment: It can be 1.69 only if you are not rounding it. There has to be rounding at some point, if you want the value to be rounded to nearest .05. Sure, you can also do a number of if-then-else cases to cover everything, but that is not really needed. If round doesn't work in your version, floor definitely is, so use cout << floor(qtPrice*20 + 0.05)*0.05, where qtPrice is your starting price.

Comment: Is there any functions or includes?

http://puu.sh/lOYrX/7bc9c0ec48.png

doesnt fix it. Output still 1.69....

Price() returns the starting price.

Comment: By qtPrice I didn't mean starting price of the product, but starting price of this rounding procedure. :) So your total should include floor(price()*quantity()*1.13(if taxed)*20+0.05)*0.05

Comment: it rounded it down, from 1.69 to 1.65

Comment: I think if i just add 0.05 to the total it would fix itself.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, what a stupid mistake on my part... When rounding with floor, you should add 0.5 in this case, not 0.05, as you're rounding to whole number. So use floor(price()*quantity()*1.13(if taxed)*20+0.5)*0.05 and that should finally work.

Comment: Compiling this on g++ says i have not declared floor. are you sure there isnt any declarations for it?

Comment: If it doesn't compile, try to use #include <cmath>. If it still won't work, you could perhaps try to reference a library while compiling.