# read write file to 5 decimal places in borland c++

Tags: writetofile, borland-c++

I writing with borland C++ compiler. I want to read numbers with 5 decimal places from text file then save it into another text file.

I wrote my program as below:

```
main
{
double Bid[25], Be1[25],Bn1[25];
int i,no=10,j,p;
char filename[30];

    ifstream fp1;
    fp1.open("bufile2.txt");
    cout<<"\n id  lat long";
    for (i=1;i<=no;i++)
        {
        fp1>>Bid[i]>>Be1[i]>>Bn1[i];
        cout<<"\n "<<i<<"  "<<Bid[i]<<"  "<<Be1[i]<<"   "<<Bn1[i];
        }
    fp1.close();

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

my input file is as follow:

```
id lat long 
1   101.28411   2.91245
2   101.28211   2.91345
3   101.28301   2.91345
4   101.28401   2.91345
5   101.28501   2.91345
6   101.28001   2.91445
7   101.28101   2.91445
8   101.28201   2.91445
9   101.28301   2.91445
10  101.28401   2.91445
```

my problem is, the Be1[i]... not outputting 5 decimal number in my stored file "result.txt". It only give me 3 decimal places. The result is as followed:

```
id lat long
1   101.284 2.91245
2   101.282 2.91345
3   101.283 2.91345
4   101.284 2.91345
5   101.285 2.91345
6   101.280 2.91445
7   101.281 2.91445
8   101.282 2.91445
9   101.283 2.91445
10  101.284 2.91445
```

Help me please

Comment: please format your code so it is better readable without scrolling as much to the left (about 70 chars per line should be fine). Sort the formatting as well, you keep switching different styles of coding (f.e. linebreak after { or not, indentation inside {} or not - this makes it hard to read. Every "good" IDE has tools to format consistently.

Comment: I suggest you start from the simplest program that does some part of your assignment (just read and write one single number), and get it to work first like you want. Then once that's done, build upon it.

Comment: Dear M.Prokhorov, re-phase my code to. could please advise the reason of not getting result in 5 decimal.

Comment: Not sure about Borland C++, but it works with GCC. Add `cout.precision(8);` as the first line of your function.

Comment: Duplicated BTW: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: Abelisto, it does't work with Borland C++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097437/593144

Comment: @eddyjunaidy: `cin.precision()` (or `std::setprecision()`) is the correct way to handle this, so *which* Borland C++ compiler are you using exactly that this does not work in?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it work with 
stackoverflow.com/a/35097437/593144. TQ Abelisto