# How do I move a decimal point left while maintaining number of digits displayed?

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal, setw

I currently have a function that takes in a vector of structs, including all floats, and should return some values after a simple calculation.

My cout function is simply

```
void taxPrint(std::vector<TaxPayer> &citizen)
{
    int loops = 0;

    std::cout << "\nTaxes due for this year: \n" << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Tax Payer #" << loops << " : $" << citizen[loops].taxes << std::endl;
        loops++;
}
while (loops + 1 <= SIZE);
```

and the resulting output in console is

```
Tax Payer #0 : $450000
Tax Payer #1 : $210000
```

That said, I want it to be

```
Tax Payer #0 : $4500.00
Tax Payer #1 : $2100.00
```

I've been messing around with setw() and setprecision() but I don't exactly understand how they work.

Comment: What is `citizen[loops].taxes`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: I can remove that from the example altogether, my issue is strictly with how to display the correct decimals

Comment: No you shouldn't really remove it, since it seems to be a key part of your problem. With the output you show it seems to be an *integer* value, which means there are no decimals to display.

Comment: It's a float. I'm just talking about a function that outputs these numbers like I said, but if you want to see more the full program I have it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488995/c-vectors-of-structs-and-passing-them-error-process-returned-1073741819

Comment: For starters, have you tried to divide the value by `100`?

Comment: I guess I didn't think of that. Out of curiosity though, is there a way to handle this with just tools provided by iomanip?

Comment: No, since your value isn't what you want, you can't "magically" insert decimal points where it doesn't belong. You need to print the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::setw`, actually has **nothing** to do with *value precision*, it is for padding string with prefixes like: `001-0123-9124` (Padded with `0`)

**Example:** `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << 5 << std::endl;` will print *00005*

Here is how to use it using [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
void taxPrint(std::vector<TaxPayer> &citizen)
{
    int loops = 0;

    std::cout << "\nTaxes due for this year: \n" << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Tax Payer #" << loops << " : $" << std::setprecision(2) 
                  << std::fixed << citizen[loops].taxes / 100. << std::endl;
        loops++;
    }
    while (loops + 1 <= SIZE);
} // Don't miss this bracket!
```

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515592/how-to-use-setprecision-in-c) question to know more about specifying a fixed precision to a value...